# Using indirect variable references in a Bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I have lots of old log files in a directory, with apps logs generated every month to this directory. I want to use a script to remove only the last month old logs.

> This is my file logsDir , these files are 0kb, i have created for question understanding

```
[root@dasari9 logDir]# ls -ltr
total 136
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 20 12:22 ram.logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 20 12:22 ram9.logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 20 12:22 ram8.logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 20 12:22 ram7.logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 20 12:22 ram6.logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 20 12:22 ram69.logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 20 12:22 ram68.logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 20 12:22 ram67.logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 20 12:22 ram66.logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 20 12:22 ram5.logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 20 12:22 ram59.logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 20 12:22 ram58.logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 20 12:22 ram57.logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 20 12:22 ram56.logs
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 20 12:22 ram4.logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 20 12:22 ram49.logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 20 12:22 ram48.logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 20 12:22 ram47.logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 20 12:22 ram46.logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 20 12:22 ram3.logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 20 12:22 ram39.logs
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 20 12:22 ram38.logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 20 12:22 ram37.logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 20 12:22 ram36.logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 20 12:22 ram2.logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 20 12:22 ram29.logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 20 12:22 ram28.logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 20 12:22 ram27.logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 20 12:22 ram26.logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 20 12:22 ram1.logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 20 12:22 ram19.logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 20 12:22 ram18.logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 20 12:22 ram17.logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 20 12:22 ram16.logs
```

This is my `logs.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

Jan=Dec Feb=Jan Mar=Feb Apr=Mar May=Apr Jun=May Jul=Jun Aug=Jul Sep=Aug Oct=Sep Nov=Oct Dev=Nov

DIR=/logDir
cd $DIR
if [ $DIR -eq $PWD ]; then 
PWD=$(pwd)
cmd=$(date |awk '{print $2}') 
dat=$(ls -ltr |grep $cmd |awk '{print $9}')
rm -rf $dat
else
echo " enterend in the wrong dir"
fi
```

but it's failing to get that variable value `Apr=Mar`

This is the output, I'm trying to delete `Apr` files

```
[root@dasari9 /]# bash -x log.sh 
+ Jan=Dec
+ Feb=Jan
+ Mar=Feb
+ Apr=Mar
+ May=Apr
+ Jun=May
+ Jul=Jun
+ Aug=Jul
+ Sep=Aug
+ Oct=Sep
+ Nov=Oct
+ Dev=Nov
+ DIR=/logDir
+ cd /logDir
++ pwd
+ PWD=/logDir
+ '[' /logDir == /logDir ']'
++ date
++ awk '{print $2}'
+ cmd=Apr
++ ls -ltr
++ grep '$Apr'
++ awk '{print $9}'
+ dat=
+ rm -rf
```

Comment: Without knowing the content of the directory, it's hard to understand what's happening here. What happens when you run `ls -ltr | grep Mar` in the directory? Does the output show some of the files, and does the output have 9 columns?

Comment: Better post the code in http://www.shellcheck.net/ for an initial safety check. Also, `Jan=Dec Feb=Jan Mar=Feb Apr=Mar May=Apr Jun=May Jul=Jun Aug=Jul Sep=Aug Oct=Sep Nov=Oct Dev=Nov` looks quite weird.

Comment: running with ls -ltr | grep Mar |awk '{print $9}' , it gives  all march file names only , with out all fields like type of file , time,date..etc..I'm adding files also now

Comment: Why don't you use `find` for this? Something like `find $DIR -mtime +30` will find you files that have not been modified for more than 30 days.

Comment: Or better yet; this mostly reduces your script to one line: `find . -mtime +30 -exec echo 'rm {}' \; | bash -x`

Comment: @ Filipe Gonçalves some times we used all logs and modify regularly.. i want to solve this issue using that kind of dynamic values ..

Comment: I've added an answer to show how to resolve the indirect reference...

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves Instead of `-exec ...`, you could simply use `-delete`, which will delete any found files.

Comment: @nwinkler Ah, yeah, that's a good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're looking for an *indirect variable reference*. Your `$cmd` variable points to the variable `$Apr` and you want to use the value of `$Apr`.

Here's how you can do this (just the relevant lines):

```
cmd=$(date | awk '{print $2}')
eval month=\$$cmd
dat=$(ls -ltr | grep $month | awk '{print $9}')
```

The `eval` command resolves the indirect reference created by `\$$cmd`.

More details here: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html